# Which Frontend technology I should used with backend java for Inventory management System

Tags: java, web-services, angularjs, inventory

I want to develop an **Inventory Management System** I am confused in choosing front-end. Mostly IMS are desktop application/software I am thinking to make a `web application` that could be further used for **Business Intelligence** is it a good choice? In some organizations I have seen developers are using `Java` and `AngularJS` I think I am good with java but not have enough idea of `AngularJS`. What you you suggest me for both desktop application and front-end.

Comment: Your requirements are pretty vague.  You should edit your question and add more details/requirements.

Comment: The question you're asking is "Is a web application good choice for a IMS?", which is off-topic here. You could ask such a question on UX.SE maybe. Next, IMHO Java and JavaScript are not comparable and in any case it depends on the outcome of the previous question. As it is, the question is hardly about a "software recommendation" but more about decision making.